# Can we reuse a layout xml on different fragments on Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment

I have a pager with 3 pages where I just set a background image. Instead of creating page1.xml, page2.xml and page3.xml. Can I create just page.xml and set the background by code?  Is that a good solution or is bad for android to load images on real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, you can set the background image in your onCreate() methode:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    findViewById(R.id.my_root).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

or you can use a theme if you like that more

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.my_theme);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

and then set the windowBackground in your custom theme.